# Accessing a div element in a partial view (that is repeated) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I am looking to achieve the following:

I have 2 views, 1 partial and 1 index.

In the index I have a loop that goes through a list of models and passes each item to the partial view.

Now for each item in that list of models I want to be able to a modal dialog. I.e. for a list of user posts there is a buy or sell button on each post. All of which use the same div/modal. Is there any way I can retrieve say a textbox value from within that modal dialog, specifically for the dialog whose "Buy now" button I've clicked on?

Code:

Index:

```
 @model IEnumerable<BRApplication.Models.MarketPost> 

 @{
     foreach (var m in Model) {
             if (m.IsBuy) {
                 <li>
                         @Html.Partial("BuyPost_Partial", m) 
                 </li>
             } 
     }
 }
```

and in the `BuyPost_Partial` have this:

```
 <div id="mdlEmail" class="none">
     Please enter an email the owner of this book can contact you with. <br/>
      @Html.TextBox("txtRespondantEmail", "", new { id = "txtRespondantEmail" })
 </div>
```

I want to be able to get the value of the `txtRespondantEmail` textbox.

Any ideas on how I can make this textbox unique for each post? I don't know how I would access the ID if I append an ID to it either.

o JS for the Modal (I've put it in the Index.cshtml file)

```
         function EmailDialog() {
            // alert("email");
             $("#mdlEmail").dialog({
                 height: 200,
                 width: 500,
                 modal: true,
                 buttons: {
                     "Confirm": function () {
                         MailNow();
                         $(this).dialog("close");
                     }
                 }
             });
         }
```

In the MailNow() function I try to access the textbox value with this line of jQuery:

```
 var RespondantEmail = $("#txtRespondantEmail").val();
```

Buy now handler:

```
   $(function () {
             $("#btnBuyNow").click(function () {
                 var email = $("#email").text();
                 alert(email);
                 if (email) {
                     EmailDialog();
                 } else {
                     FacebookLink();
                 }
             });
         });
```

The textbox is in the `EmailDialog()`.

Comment: I don't see a button in your partial. Do you have a buynow button for each item?

Comment: @DaveA yes I do have a buy now button in the partial the html is too long for me to paste it here lol, but yes there is a buy now button in the partial page

Comment: please share your event handler for your buy now buttons

Comment: @Dave Kay Sure  .....

Comment: add an attribute to each button, something like `_id = txtRespondantEmail` then in your jquery, access the attribute as `$(this).attr('_id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are iterating through `Model`, I assume there will be multiple occurrences of your partial. Therefore, you should not assign `id='txtRespondantEmail'` to a textbox because `id` means that you have only single such element. Make it a class: `class='txtRespondantEmail'` also you need an. You also need some unique identifier on textbox. Does your `MarketPost` have an Id? If so, put attribute id on it: `id='txtRespondantEmail-'@Model.Id`.

Then you'll be able to get your value like that:

```
var val = $('#txtRespondantEmail-1').val();
```

**Update**

It would be more proper to ask you why you need that value? You probably want to make a call to the server when something is typed in that textbox? If that's the case, create a button next to the textbox. Give it a class, say: 'btn-save'. Then make ajax call to the server where you will be saving the value like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-save', function(){
    var val = $(this).siblings('.txtRespondantEmail').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/controllername/actionname/',
        type: 'POST'
        data: new { text: val },
        success: function(data){
            alert('done');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: how will I access that particular post? I mean keep track of the counter in my jQuery?

Comment: I think that's the best idea! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your model looks like, but is there anything in the model that you are passing to the partial view that is unique so that you can attach it to the id of the textbox.

For example is you have something like m.ID and you could try

```
@Html.TextBox("txtRespondantEmail", "", new { id = "txtRespondantEmail" + m.ID })
```

I do not have VS right now so I could not test this, but you can give it a try.

$('[id^="txtRespondantEmail"]') - This will return all textboxes that start with 'txtRespondantEmail'

Comment: If I do add the id of the post to the id of the textbox, how do I access it from within the jQuery? That's the problem I'm running into right now. How do I pass

Comment: You can get all textboxes created with jQuery. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant how do I keep track of which textbox I am at exactly. Like when the user clicks on the "Confirm" button how do I know exactly textbox was edited (whats the index?)

Comment: If you are trying to get the textbox next to the button the user clicked then you need to add the id of the textbox to the id or other attribute of the button and go from there. I'm assuming you have something like: textbox - button repeated line after line